# Using Factory get product collection with product name in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, product, product-collection

I get product collection using `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory` in block( dependency injection), the result doesn't have **name** attribute,

The similar Q&A(ObjectManager) here  [Product collection has no name attribute how can I get it magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137734/product-collection-has-no-name-attribute-how-can-i-get-it-magento2/137892) doesn't work.

The detail codes is below, my question is "*how to add **name** attribute in the block collection*"?

---

### Detail codes

In block:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products
        return $collection->getData();
    }
}
```

In template (.phtml) file:

```
<?php
$productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($productCollection);
echo "</pre>";
```

### Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 1
            [attribute_set_id] => 15
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => 24-MB01
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2017-08-14 07:07:01
            [updated_at] => 2017-08-14 07:07:01
        )

    ...

)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are attributes that may not work properly with `getData()` such as the product price because **getData() contains only main table data.**

Return **full collection object(without getData())** in `getProductCollection()` function

```
public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products
    return $collection;
}
```

Now you can get product id, name, sku and other information with getter function like `getId()`, `getName()`, `getSku()`, ... in phtml

```
<?php

$productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();

foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    echo $product->getId();
    echo $product->getName();
}
```

Comment: Upvote. But strange, my last question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191300/magento-2-product-collection-invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach?noredirect=1&lq=1 collection without getData() will result **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**, why it works now? I am confused.

Comment: Becuase you use `getData()` in foreach $product object in previous question  and in this question you use `getData()` on whole collection object

Comment: Hi @PrincePatel,
Can we filter the media_gallery direct in product collection because I have more then 20,000 products, so if try to load each product so it will take so much time.

You have any idea?

Comment: Yes you can filter the collection by image like: __$collection->addAttributeToFilter('small_image',array('notnull'=>'','neq'=>'no_selection'));__ in product collection

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Getter functions `getName()`

**From**

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($productCollection);
echo "</pre>";
```

**you don't get data from above code**.`print_r($productCollection);` ***Only given data of product model of main table catalog_product_entity***

You need to run foreach loop for getting name  and inside it you will get your desire result

```
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
echo $product->getName()

}
```